# Dropdown menu won't close on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I've got a dropdown menu that opens on mobile when the user clicks on "Projects". When the user clicks on "Projects" again, I need the dropdown menu to close. I can't get it to close on the second click though. I'm assuming it's a quick fix, but I've got nothing.

Here is a Fiddle with all the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ch8j3zgs/1/

Here is the script:

```
function displayDropdown() {
var x = document.getElementById("nav ul ul");
if (x.style.display === "none") {
x.style.display = "block";
} else {
x.style.display = "none";
}
}

function displayDropdown() {
var x = document.getElementById("nav ul ul");
if (x.style.display === "block") {
x.style.display = "none";
} else {
x.style.display = "block";
}
}
```

Thank you guys! I appreciate it!

EDIT: I realize it is going to be hard to reproduce the error in the fiddle since you all can probably hover which works great! Hopefully seeing the code in the fiddle will help though! :)

Comment: when you click on it, there's an error `TypeError: x is null, can't access property "style" of it` - because `var x = document.getElementById("nav ul ul");` is probably not what you wanted (`nav ul ul` is not an ID)

Comment: Not a valid `id`. Also, you should know that to test for a style property it should be set by you first.

Comment: Hmmmm. The first script is actually working great though and opens the dropdown menu on click using the same id...

Comment: `The first script is actually working great` impossible, since it can never run because having two `displayDropdown` functions means only the second exists ... and they both have the invalid id .... perhaps `document.querySelector("#nav ul ul")` will make it work ... though your logic in both versions of the function is slightly flawed

Comment: Are you using CSS to open the menu?

Comment: @JaromandaX , my apologies, The first script was working correctly prior to adding the second one. If you remove the second script, the dropdown does open onclick which is strange considering the id is invalid hmmm. I'll try adding the # before and use querySelector

Comment: @PHPglue Yes, CSS

Comment: `The first script was working correctly prior to adding the second one` no, it wasn't, it can't, and it doesn't, because the ID is invalid

Comment: You already have Jquery loaded in your fiddle. Why don't you use the toggle method? https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_toggle.asp

Comment: @JaromandaX I see. The code in the JSFiddle is the only code I was using related to the opening/closing of the dropdown menu so I don't know how it was opening on click. Any ideas on why it was working?

Comment: nope, sorry, no idea how that could ever have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do that,
Note - I've removed  two same methods (`displayDropdown`) in the `JS` and `:hover` styles in the `CSS`

```js
$('#nav ul>li').click(function(){
 $(this).find('ul').toggle();
});
```

```css
#nav {
 width: 100%;
 background-color: white;
}

#projects {
 display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #000000;
 list-style-type: none;
 text-align: center;
 margin: auto;
 padding-top: 6px;
 padding-right: 0px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 0px;
  cursor:pointer;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

#nav ul ul {
 width: calc(100% - 20px);
 list-style-type: none;
 font-weight: normal;
 display: none;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}



#one {
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 color: #000000;
 background-color: white;
}

#one:active {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}

#one:hover {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
}

a.blocklink {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: inherit;
 display: block;
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
 #nav ul ul {
  width: 20%;
 }
 #footer-nav ul ul {
  width: 20%;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nav">
   <ul>
      <li id="projects">
         Projects
         <ul>
            <a href="/one" class="blocklink">
               <li id="one">One</li>
            </a>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome, Yeah please try to understand and apply. Happy coding !

Comment: If I wanted to keep the original HTML structure I had, would I just change the ".find('ul')" to ".find('ul ul')" ? I'm hoping to be able to keep the original structure as I may add more li items to the top ul! :) Thanks!

Comment: better you give that `ul` a class name like `<ul class="child-menu-item">` then use `find(ul .child-menu-item)`

Comment: Ooo great idea! And for the first part of the script "$('#menu>li')", I can just use "$('#nav>li')" for the original HTML structure, correct? Thanks!!

Comment: I'm using this and can't seem to get it to work, any of this syntax stick out as incorrect or not aligning with the original html structure? Thank you!            $('#nav>li').click(function(){
 $(this).find('ul .dropdown').toggle();
})

Comment: @JohnSmith Since you're struggling, I've edited my solution to your exact same html structure. Please check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it. Have a great rest of your day sir.

Comment: No worries. Happy coding. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think Bootstrap will help you

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Project
</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">One</a>
</div>
```

Then use Javascript/JQuery to toggle the button

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown(){
    //code here
}
```